# realm sumOfProperty does not give most recent update

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, realm

Realm 0.96.3 master.

I have a test that creates two records of `Person`. Each person has an `NSNumber<RLMDouble> *walkDistance` property.

### model of Person

```
@interface Person : RLMObject
@property NSString  *id;
@property NSString  *name;
@property NSDate    *birthdate;
@property NSNumber<RLMDouble>  *walkDistance;
@property RLMArray<Dog *><Dog> *dogs;
@end
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Person)
```

### viewDidLoad

In a tableview, I created a `RLMRealm self.database` and a `RLMResult
self.persons`.  on the main thread in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.bgq = dispatch_queue_create("com.salesram.bgqueu", NULL);
self.database = [self getEncryptedRealm];
self.persons = [[Person objectsInRealm:self.database withPredicate:nil]
__typeof__(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
self.token = [self.database addNotificationBlock:^(NSString * _Nonnull notification, RLMRealm * _Nonnull realm) {
    [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
    [weakSelf calculateTotal];
}];
```

The `getEncryptedRealm` is a standard Realm creation:

```
    NSData *key = [NSData dataWithBytes:c length:64];
    // Open the encrypted Realm file
    RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
    config.encryptionKey = key;
    NSError *error;
    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:config error:&error];
    assert(realm != nil);

    return realm;
```

### createData:

I have a function `createData` to create 2 persons in a background thread. Another function clears all objects in a background thread then add 2 new person. Both of them use GCD same queue. So they runs sequentially. *[are on the same thread and (Edit: they can be run in different threads)]*.

```
- (void)createData:(int)seq
{
dispatch_async(self.bgq, ^{
    NSLog(@"start %i", seq);
    @autoreleasepool {
        RLMRealm *db = [self getEncryptedRealm];
        //[db refresh];
        [db beginWriteTransaction];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            NSString *pid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", arc4random()%100];
            Person *person = [Person createOrUpdateInRealm:db withValue:@{@"id": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", pid]}];
            person.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Person Name # %@", pid];
            person.walkDistance = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:arc4random()%3+1];
            // omits some code of creating dogs...
        }
        [db commitWriteTransaction];

        NSLog(@"end %i", seq);
    }
});
}
```

### clearDB:

The clearDB will delete everything and recreate everything on a background serial queue.

```
- (IBAction)clearDB:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    dispatch_async(self.bgq, ^{
        RLMRealm *db = [self getEncryptedRealm];
        [db beginWriteTransaction];
        [db deleteAllObjects];
        [db commitWriteTransaction];
    });
    [self createData:1];
}
```

### calculateTotal

Then I have a function on the main thread to calculate the sum of `walkDistance`. It will be triggered by the Realm notification on commitWrite.

```
- (void)calculateTotal
{
    assert([NSThread isMainThread]);
    NSNumber *total = [self.persons sumOfProperty:@"walkDistance"];
    double miles = 0;
    for (Person *person in self.persons) {
        miles += [person.walkDistance doubleValue];
    }
    NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %0.0f", total, miles];
    NSLog(@"%@", title);
}
```

### Problem

The problem is when I trigger `clearDB` with a button, most of the time I got a total of distance as 0 with the `sumOfProperty` method. The for loop add always work.

From the log, it seems two notifications was fired and the `calculateTotal` is called two times, one after the clear, one after the population. But the `sumOfProperty` seems most of the time stick with the first time value, which is 0. You can see the last line of log shows **0 - 6** Instead it should be **6 - 6**

#### NSLog output

```
2015-12-10 21:25:38.686 dbrealmtest[18746:3258269] start 1
2015-12-10 21:25:38.686 dbrealmtest[18746:3258213] 1.358118751448067e-312 - 0
2015-12-10 21:25:38.692 dbrealmtest[18746:3258269] end 1
2015-12-10 21:25:38.693 dbrealmtest[18746:3258213] 0 - 6
```

Is this a known issue? a bug? or anything I missed?

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend, if you don't check the error pointer that you don't pass one at all. This will cause that Realm's initializer throws an exception instead, which gives you a more helpful error message on the log than `assert(realm != nil)`.

Comment: Yo wrote "Both of them use GCD same queue. So they are on the same thread and runs sequentially.". That's not true. GCD gives no guarantee about the executing thread, beside the main queue.

Comment: @marius I don't understand your first comment. Could you explain a little more? For the 2nd comment, Yes. You are right. They are not executed by the same thread but just sequentially. That is why I added a statement in the beginning of each dispatch_async to get a new Realm. But it should not cause the issue I saw, right?

Comment: @marius The assertion in the create Realm was always passed. So in each background thread, the Realm is successfully created.

Comment: You're right. The fact about GCD is not causing the issue, you see here. I was just pointing that out for further reference, so that you and maybe others don't base on wrong assumptions. :)

Comment: I commented over on the GitHub issue, which you created, what we would need to investigate that.

Comment: To my first comment: that was based on: `NSError *error; RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:config error:&error]; assert(realm != nil);`. That could be done better by `RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:config error:nil];`. This will throw an exception, which is more meaningful than the assert.

Comment: @marius The code is available in Github: https://github.com/shaozi/RealmSumReproduce.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update for the records: This turned out after [further investigation](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2984) to be a bug, which is fixed since version 0.97.1.